# How to add button to last row in gridvew of devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I want below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk10s.png)
I want to add a button to the last row of gridview.
Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done this using footer.

```
        public static void CustomDrawFooter(DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl gridControl, GridView gridView)
        {
            gridView.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;
            gridView.FooterPanelHeight = 40;

            // Handle this event to paint the footer panel manually
            gridView.CustomDrawFooter += (s, e) => {
                int Hoffset = 10;
                int Voffset = 5;
                e.DefaultDraw();

                markRectangle = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + Hoffset, e.Bounds.Y + Voffset, e.Bounds.Width - 2 * Hoffset, e.Bounds.Height - 2 * Voffset);

                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
                e.Appearance.FillRectangle(e.Cache, e.Bounds);
                e.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
                e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
                e.Appearance.FontSizeDelta = 1;
                e.Appearance.Font = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 10);
                e.Appearance.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
                e.Cache.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(184, 169, 126)), markRectangle);
                e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, "Show more items...", markRectangle);

            };
        }
```

I added MouseUp Event.

```
        private void GridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GridHitInfo hitInfo = dmGridView.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
            if(hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.Footer)
            {
                if ((e.Location.X >= markRectangle.X && e.Location.X <= markRectangle.X + markRectangle.Width) &&
                    (e.Location.Y >= markRectangle.Y && e.Location.Y <= markRectangle.Y + markRectangle.Height))
                    MessageBox.Show("HAHAHAHAHAH");
            }
        }
```

This works.